# Is it possible to disable specific warnings in Komodo Edit?

Tags: javascript, ide, komodo, komodoedit

Komodo Edit divides warnings into two categories: regular and strict.  Of the strict warnings, some - for example, the warning when a dictionary definition has a trailing comma - are useful to me, while others aren't.

Is there a way, perhaps even through editing Komodo resource files, to disable specific warnings within the 'strict' category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe installing the [kJSlint addon](http://community.activestate.com/node/3621) can help? It gives you control over jslint, equal to the [official jslint options](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options).